# spark use log4j to log to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, logging, apache-spark, log4j, hdfs

I have a spark application, is there a way to use log4j to log to HDFS without a flume appender? 
(I am not an expert but since I do not have to log a lot using Flume looks like an overkill)

Suggestions welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the point is that the log is already saved in HDFS, by the yarn aggregator, you can get them doing

```
yarn logs --applicationId application_1441635924531_0065 | less
```

where the applicationId number comes up on the shell when you launch the spark-submit.